# Why in ios systems if I accept to receive push notifications I get a warning message in response?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, push-notification

i am developing an application with ionic 5.
The application receives push notifications from firebase without any problems.
But every time I install the application on IOS it asks me to allow the receipt of push notifications, if I accept (as normal) a warning message is displayed.
The message informs me that if you select no, I will not be able to receive notifications, but I have selected yes.
Is there any way to handle this?
That message is handled by the operating system, did you have the same problem?

Comment: What's the warning message?

Comment: We found a function that was called twice and on ios it checked again if the user had agreed to receive the push notifications